# Is there a way to do content based routing on a message's exchange pattern in Camel 2.15?

Tags: apache-camel

I currently have a process that needs to do some routing based on a message's exchange pattern. If a message is InOut, then the route ends and whatever the message contains gets sent back to the callback location. If the message is InOnly then the message gets routed somewhere else. The code is below:

```
...
.process(new Processor(){
    public void process(Exchange e) throws Exception {
        e.getIn().setHeader("ExchangePattern", e.getPattern().name());
    }
})
.choice()
    .when(header("ExchangePattern").isEqualTo("InOnly"))
        .to(DESTINATION);
```

I know that in Camel 2.16 you can get the exchange pattern via the simple expression (exchange.getPattern.getName) but that's not available in 2.15. Is there a more elegant want do doing the routing or am I stuck with the ugly routing logic above?

Comment: Maybe you can get it in another expression language in Camel 2.15. Did you have a look at SpEL or OGNL.? If you have any of them already in your dependencies and it's supported it would be better to utilize them for this. But adding extra dependencies just for that...I don't know if it would be better than your current solution.

Comment: I think you are stuck because unless you check it via the simple language you need to set the header value yourself and then verify in the choice.